what controller rate in ros2_control is considered as continuous?
I need to move a 4 wheel cart from one position(p1(x1, y1)) to other(p2(x2, y2) in t seconds. I calculate x and y speed as follows using speed = distance/time:
x_speed = (x2-x1)/t
y_speed = (y2-y1)/t
Now the values produced by this formula would mean that I need to have CONTINUOUS speed of "x_speed" in x direction and "y_speed" in the y direction for 1 second.
QUESTION:
I want to know what controller rate in ros2_control(any controller, diff_drive, tricycle etc) is considered as CONTINUOUS? For example 10hz, 100hz, or 1000hz.

There is a parameter in the controller(usually name with "timeout") which specifies the amount for which the controller will execute the received command after receiving it. This could be set to move the robot continuously. For example for the ros2 differential drive it is "cmd_vel_timeout".
Earlier I thought I need to publish the commands continuously to make the robot move that is why I asked "what controller rate in ros2_control is considered as continuous?".
Thanks

I do not understand your question.
If you want to reach that point directly with constant velocity profile, you can calculate the speed as you have written and send that to the controller. Why does the update rate of the controller matter?

I am unable to reach the desired location by publishing the calculate velocity once. I think it is because the velocity is being published only once and to reach the goal, i would have to apply that velocity constantly for 1 second. To do so i need to publish that velocity multiple time within a second.

The controller rate matters because of the same reason. Suppose the controller rate is 4hz, in this case, the robot will move 4 times in a second with the provided velocity. Its speed would be increasing and decreasing due to this. Due to this reason that moment would not be considered as continuous because the velocity is not applied at all times in one second. I feel the controller rate should be infinity? Do'nt know how would i set it.

your robot will travel a fourth of the distance in 0.25s, I still do not understand your question.

I will try to simplify. Let's say I want to apply x and y velocity of 0.5 each. Now when I publish this velocity once, for how long will the controller apply this velocity to the wheels? For example If it applies it for 0.2 second, distance traveled would be 0.1 (0.5 * 0.2), if it applies it for 0.7 seconds, distance would be 0.35(0.5 * 0.7).

that depends on the controller you are using. typical implementation of references via topic is: keep the old command until a new one is received.
